# cannot create user in the keycloak. Getting 403 status

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to access the create a user in the keycloak programmatically. But I am getting 403 as a status code. I am following the below link.

https://technology.first8.nl/programmatically-adding-users-in-keycloak/

Can anyone help me? Thanks In advance

I have using the following code to create user

```
Keycloak kc = Keycloak.getInstance(
                     "http://{server name}:8080/auth",
                     "{realm name}", // the realm to log in to
                     "{useraname}", 
                     "{password}",  // the user
                     "{client id}",
                     "{client secret key}");

            CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
            credential.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
            credential.setValue("test123");
            UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
            user.setUsername("codeuser");
            user.setFirstName("sampleuser1");
            user.setLastName("password");

            user.setCredentials(Arrays.asList(credential));
            user.setEnabled(true);
            Response result = kc.realm("{realm name}").users().create(user);
```

response.status is coming as 403

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I faced the same issue. This is how i fixed it.

1. Create a role that has at least a realm-management role of `manage-users`
   [image]

[image]

**UI update for server 9.0.2**
[image: UI update for server 9.0.2]

2. Go to your client's `Scope` tab and add the role to your `Realm Roles`
   [image]

Comment: This works for me with KC server 3.4.0.Final and the same version of admin client; fwiw the Gradle stanza I have is `compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-admin-client', version: '3.4.0.Final'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359979/keycloak-admin-rest-api-unknown-error-for-update-user-api explained better.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue with KeyCloak 9.0.3.
What finally worked for me was:

1. Use the admin-cli client with client credentials on the target realm (where I am trying to create the user)

```
curl \
  -d "client_id=admin-cli\
  -d "client_secret=<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
  "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

I am not sure why, but using the admin client on the master realm simply did not work for me.

2. Set up the admin-cli client in the target realm with the role as mentioned in the correct answer above.
3. In addition to adding the new role to Scope, I also had to add the role to Service Account Roles.

BTW client credentials access token is not even mentioned as an option in the Admin Rest API docs for Keycloak 9.0.3, but it does work.

Comment: "I also had to add the role to Service Account Roles" +1

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using `admin` user from `master` realm.

You need to assign proper roles like `manage-users` role from `realm-management` client for the user which you are using to get instance the instance of Keycloak.

[image: Adding realm-management roles to the user]

Comment: I have assigned the roles as shown above still I am getting the status as forbidden

Comment: Can you find the error message using  ErrorRepresentation error = response.readEntity(ErrorRepresentation.class);  error.getErrorMessage()

Comment: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type */* and type class org.keycloak.representations.idm.ErrorRepresentation 
this exception occurs when I add the above line of code

Comment: You need to have resteasy-jackson2-provider jar in your dependency

Answer (score 4):

If you use `Service Accounts` to authenticate, you need to add roles of precedent answer in the tab `Service Accounts Roles`

Like below [image: KeyCloak Client Admin Cli Service Account Tab]