# Keycloak Admin Rest API unknown_error for update user API

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to add a custom attribute to a user using Admin Rest API.
When i try with default master realm, its working fine. But when i try it with another realm that i created, it yields "unknown_error".

I have attached the screenshot of request below.
[image]

Comment: Please check what token you are passing

Comment: Please check Keycloak logs

Comment: I am having the same issue, running the Keycloak version 10.0.2 docker image. No logs.

Answer (score 46):

You haven't granted related permissions to your realm.

Go to 'Clients' -> select your client -> 'Service Account Roles':

- In the client roles dropdown box, click `realm-management`
- In Available Roles box, select related roles. Try `manage-users` and `view-users`.

Then get a new access token and try your API call again.

[image]

Comment: This is actually the right answer. First make sure you configure the admin-cli client of your realm with "Acces type" = confidential and turn on "Service Accounts enabled" (https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/keycloak-rest-api-create-a-new-user/)

Comment: Oh man, maaany thanks, you saved me an hour! Is there any doc describing these builtin roles?

Comment: In my keycloak installed on-premise, in my "Admin-cli" client, not appear "real-management" in Client Roles :(

Comment: I again, solved! in the version 17.0.1, april 2022, the name es "master-realm" and not "real-management"

Comment: In the client roles you should select the realm you want to give access to. In my case my realm is called "testrealm" so I would select "testrealm-realm"

Answer (score 8):

I found that I had to use the `admin-cli` client in the `master` realm to use the admin REST API.  When you look at the master realm, there is an admin role that does not exist in sub-realms.  That admin role seems to be necessary to access the admin REST API successfully.

My suggestion is that you can create a client in the master realm as a service account, then assign the admin role to that client.  You can then use that unique admin service account for API access by other programs.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the Admin API needs to be accessed via the `admin-cli` client.

I got a 403 `{"error":"unknown_error"}` when I wanted to use a copy of the default admin-cli client.

Comment: This works for me. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the `admin-cli` client for Admin API, yes. But you aren't limited to this. Creating a particular confidential client with enabled flow "Service accounts roles" is also a way and it's even better.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using **Keycloak 21**

what I had to do was:

- Go to **Clients**, access my client
- Go to the **Service Account Roles** tab
- then click on **Assign Role**
- Filter by "`clients`" (default is by "`realm roles`")
- then search by the desired role, in the correct realm (e.g. `manage-users`)
- Select the role and click on **Assign**

Comment: Thanks man, the clients filter was easy to miss on the UI (I also missed it when I first read your answer) Mind if I add a screenshot to your answer, to make it easier to understand?

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the attribute body like this.

```
{

"attributes": {
               "id": ["688"]
            }
}
```

Comment: I had all the permissions and actually this helped me. Sending the value as array was solution in my case. Even that it sounds a bit crazy

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Perry Harrington said, you can create a client outside your master realm and still add users to that realm. But you first need to edit the  Scope of the Admin-cli in Master Realm, and then select your realm under Service Account Roles (dropdown). After selecting the realm (e.g. myrealm-realm), you should now add the roles you would want the REST API to do, like manage-users, query-users, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found that after a lot of research ..
you have to assign roles to cli-admin . if you are using keycloack 20.0 version
Go to 'Clients' -> select your client e.g admin-cli -> 'Service Account Roles':
and then add all access you want to assign roles to cli-admin
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYBbC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You'll also get this error if you're using the wrong HTTP method.

In my case, I was accidentally using POST for the users endpoint, when instead I should have been using GET.

This would also indicate that you'll get this error if you have a malformed body when POSTing to endpoints like `clients`.

Not very helpful from Keycloak.