# Unable to create a new user using keycloak: 403 unknown_error

Tags: keycloak

This question has been asked before but none of the solutions has worked for me.
I've created a bash script to register a new user on my key cloak server. The bashscript is shown below:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
RESULT=$(curl -s --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' --data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' --data-urlencode 'client_secret=12345678-12a3-1234-bc12-d12345678910');
TOKEN=$(echo $(echo "$RESULT" | jq .access_token))
TOKEN=$(echo "${TOKEN//\"}")
echo "$TOKEN\n\n"
USER=$(curl --location -v --request POST 'http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/MyMarketplace/users' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --data-raw '{"enabled":"true", "username":"app-user"}');
echo $USER;
```

When I run this script, I keep getting the following output:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 25
< Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 20:11:40 GMT
< 
{ [25 bytes data]
100    66  100    25  100    41    974   1597 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1640
 * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"error":"unknown_error"}
```

I'm not sure why. Here's what I've tried:

- I've made sure that the URL that I'm sending the request to is correct.
- I've made sure that the username is unique and that I've provided all mandatory fields.
- In the MyMarketplace realm, I added a realm role 'admin' with a client role 'manage-users' from client 'realm-management' and I assigned this realm role to my client's scope (as per the steps given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53411469/821110) answer)
- In the Master realm, I assigned the manage-users role to the client `admin-cli`'s scope.

None of these has yielded any results so I've run out of options.
I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use and configure `admin-cli` client as you did, but in `MyMarketplace` realm. Don't use the `master` realm.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the first request to use the `MyMarketplace` ream and I've configured `admin` cli the same way (assigning it the `manage-users` client role from `realm-management`). I also updated the client_secret. After doing all that, I still get the same error.

Comment: @W.K.S time to check Keycloak logs to see what `unknown_error` means. Probably some null pointer, maybe some field in the payload are missing.

Comment: You're right, it was a null pointer exception. The request body wasn't being parsed because my content-length was not being sent. The request MUST include `Content-Length`, `Content-Type` and `Host`. The `Content-Type` must be `application/json`.

Answer (score 4):

use `http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/MyMarketplace/protocol/openid-connect/token` to obtain access_token and give `admin-cli` client `manage-users` role from `realm-management` client in `Service Account Roles` and then call `http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/MyMarketplace/users` with access token in header and `"enabled": true, "username": "user"` body.
make sure your enabled boolean look like this one and dont use `""` I think keycloak reads your request as String.
I think it will fix your problem.